# Ajax の結果を用いた条件分岐は done の中に書けば良い？

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ajaxで検査した結果を表示したいのですが、サーバーからの結果からさらにJavaScriptの`switch`文の条件を当てはめたいのですが、その`switch`文は`done`の中に書くのでしょうか？
どのようにしてサーバからの結果と`switch`文をつなげるのか分からないです。

**ソースコード**

```
$(function(){
    // ajax button click
    $('#ajax').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/home',
            type:'GET',
            data:{ 
            }
        })
     // ajaxリクエストが成功した時発動
        .done( (data) => {
            console.log("成功");
            console.log("formList:" + data);
            $('result').html(data);
            console.log(data);
        })
        .fail( (data) => {
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: doneの中に記述できます。一旦、検証している、もしくは検証しようとしているコードを質問に記載いただいたほうが回答が返ってきやすいかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

はい、doneの中に書きます。
doneに渡した処理は、ajaxリクエストが成功した時、
failに渡した処理は、ajaxリクエストが失敗した時、
alwaysに渡した処理は、ajaxリクエストが成功しても失敗しても実行されます。
ajaxの場合、dataにレスポンス内容が入っています。

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com/api/v1/event/?' + queryString,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback'
        })
        .done((data, textStatus, xhr) => {
            // success
            // 例えば、サーバが下記のような文字列を返す時
            // {
            //     "fooBars": [
            //         { "id": 1, "name":"alice" },
            //         { "id": 2, "name":"bob" }
            //     ]
            // }
            let name = data.fooBars[0].name; // alice
        })
        .fail((xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
            // error
        })
        .always((arg1, textStatus, arg3) => {
            // complete
        });
```

補足

1. Ajaxはxhr規格のヘルパー関数です。
2. リンク押下とxhrの違いは、細かい差異を除けば、ブラウザが読み直すか、js上で受け取るかだけです。
3. xhrのhttpレスポンスbodyは、htmlの代わりにjson文字列などを返します。
4. 歴史的な理由でxhrという名称ですが、通常はxml形式ではなくjson形式で返します。
5. うまく値がサーバから帰ってこない場合は、jsonp、CORS辺りが原因かもしれません。